# JAVERS: Response issue when query has .withNewObjectChanges(true)

Tags: javers

I am not sure if this is an issue or if I am doing something wrong. I noticed on application startup, when you query for changes with

> .withNewObjectChanges(true)

the response is empty list of new objects, but if you call `commit` and then query for changes again, the response is complete.

Response on application startup:

`Changes: 
Commit 9.0 done by john at 15 Nov 2018, 17:31:13 : * new object: USER/5 
Commit 8.0 done by john at 15 Nov 2018, 17:30:30 : * new object: USER/4 
Commit 6.0 done by john at 15 Nov 2018, 16:05:22 : * new object: USER/3 
Commit 4.0 done by john at 15 Nov 2018, 15:53:23 : * new object: USER/2 
Commit 1.0 done by john at 15 Nov 2018, 15:01:03 : * new object: USER/1`

Comment: could you reproduce this case as a failing test case? see how we write this kind of cases - https://github.com/javers/javers/tree/master/javers-core/src/test/groovy/org/javers/core/cases

Comment: Is it required to have the test case in Groovy?